# Find position of multiple elements in a list (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have a list of several images, some with a portrait class, and others with a landscape class:

```
<img src="/images/fullsize/007.jpg" class="portrait">
<img src="/images/fullsize/008.jpg" class="landscape">
<img src="/images/fullsize/047.jpg" class="landscape">
<img src="/images/fullsize/048.jpg" class="landscape">
<img src="/images/fullsize/049.jpg" class="landscape">
<img src="/images/fullsize/050.jpg" class="portrait">
<img src="/images/fullsize/051.jpg" class="portrait">
<img src="/images/fullsize/052.jpg" class="landscape">
<img src="/images/fullsize/053.jpg" class="landscape">
<img src="/images/fullsize/054.jpg" class="landscape">
```

How do I identify the position (within the list) of all the .portrait images and store that in a variable as an array? (i.e. for this example I need to output '1, 6, 7' or '0, 5, 6'.). I looked into using .index() but this only appears to return a single result.

Comment: This should be as simple as looping over all of the elements and adding the index of each 'correct' one to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on this example:

```
$(function() {

  var p_ind =[], l_ind=[];

  $('img').each(function(i, data) {
    if( $(data).hasClass('portrait') ) p_ind.push(i);
    else l_ind.push(i);
  });

  // Portrait
  console.log(p_ind);

  // Landscape
  console.log(l_ind);
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xacuheboru/1/watch?html,js,console)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, this works great! I hadn't yet come across the concept of loops (I'm pretty new to JavaScript) so this is incredibly useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/obv1nnv3/) with some sample code that illustrates one possible example:

```
$(function() {
    var portrait = [];
    var landscape = [];
    $("img").each(function (i, item) {
        if ($(item).hasClass("portrait")) {
            portrait.push(i);
        }
        if ($(item).hasClass("landscape")) {
            landscape.push(i);
        }
    });
    console.log("Portrait: " + portrait);
    console.log("Landscape: " + landscape);
});
```

It uses the jQuery selector to select the images and then for each one, asks if it contains a portrait or a landscape class.  Depending on the answers to these, they are pushed into arrays for later examination.